# Attribute not being passed to modelform constructor when in modelformset_factory

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form where I am trying to limit the choices which appear in the field 'question' (In this case, I only want questions which the user has created). This method has worked with other forms, but it doesn't work this time - probably because it is a ModelFormset rather than just a ModelForm

The exact error is - **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'**, which I suspect means that the 'user' object is not being passed to AnswerForm's constructor. Problem is, I have no idea why it's not being passed

```
#views.py
def add_answer(request):
        a_form = modelformset_factory(Answer, form=AnswerForm(user=request.user), fields='__all__', min_num=2, max_num=4, validate_min=True)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = a_form(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                #Do something
        return render(request, 'site/addanswer.html', {'a_form': a_form})

#forms.py
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['question'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.filter(user__username=self.user.username))

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('question', 'answer', 'correct')

#models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.question)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    correct = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.answer)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but why are you using `user.username`? `queryset=Question.objects.filter(user=self.user)` should be sufficient.

Comment: Maybe `self.user` get overwritten by `super`. Try `user = kwargs.pop('user', None)` and `self.fields['question'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.filter(user=user))`

Comment: @ilse2005 That's worked, but now it's giving me a different error - **'AnswerForm' object has no attribute '__name__'**

Comment: Could you post the traceback?

Comment: @ilse2005 The traceback is here: http://dpaste.com/3EXSVDY

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `self.user` get overwritten by `super`. Also there is no need to query `user.username`.

```
#forms.py
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['question'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.filter(user=user))

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('question', 'answer', 'correct')
```